# Разделы математики для алгоритмистов и олимпиадников

Tags: математика

Вот меня интересуют разделы математики, которые МИНИМАЛЬНО необходимы для изучения алгоритмов, а далее решения олимпиадных задач по программированию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Минимально -- школьная программа за 8-9 класс.

Желательно -- 1 курс матана, линал, дискретка(у нас последнее включает в себя структуры данных и алгоритмы)

Comment: меня больше интересует какие конкретно темы надо знать... а не просто курсы школы и универа